# How can I find the null pointer error in this Android Code involving Fragments

Tags: java, android, pointers, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have been trying for 2 hours now to find the null pointer in my code and am having no luck. I am hoping one of you far smarter individuals than I can figure it out. First off, I am following the tutorial here: http://youtu.be/Y2liEQV3tbQ?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW4lMlpHgL7UNQSGMERcDzHo  by slideNerd.

Here is what is baffling me: When in horizontal mode, the code executes perfectly and the displays are updated with correct information. This means that the horizontal portion of the if statement is working. When it is in portrait however and I click a list view icon, it immediately force closes with null pointer. The error comes from the line that reads:

```
f2b.changeTextView(index);
```

If I remove that line, the second activity opens without a problem. I am simply at a loss as to what has been causing me so much trouble.

Here are my classes:

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  FragmentA.Communicator{

    private FragmentA f1a;
    private FragmentB f2b;
    private FragmentManager manager;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        manager=getFragmentManager();

        f1a = (FragmentA) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1a);

        f1a.setCommunicator(this); //the respond method that is implemented from Fragment a

        f2b = (FragmentB) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2b);

    }

    @Override
    public void respond(int index) {

        //Check if portrait mode
        if (f2b != null && f2b.isVisible()){ //Horizontal

            f2b.changeTextView(index);
        } else { //Vertical

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("index", index);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment A:**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ListView listView;

    Communicator comm;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_a_list_view);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.chapters, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        comm.respond(position);
    }

    public void setCommunicator(Communicator communicator){
        this.comm = communicator;
    }

    //Interface to allow access between fragments
    public interface Communicator{
        public void respond(int index);
    }
}
```

**Fragment B:**

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    TextView textView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);

        return view;

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_b_text_view);


    }

    public void changeTextView(int position){

        String [] descriptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);

        textView.setText(descriptions[position]);
    }
}
```

**Activity2:**

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        int index = intent.getIntExtra("index", 0);

        //reference the fragment
        FragmentB f2b = (FragmentB) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2b);
        if (f2b != null){

            f2b.changeTextView(index);

        }

    }
}
```

And Here is the error code in the logcat:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.pgmacdesign.fragmentexamples3_flexibleui.FragmentB.changeTextView(FragmentB.java:42)
>               at com.pgmacdesign.fragmentexamples3_flexibleui.Activity2.onCreate(Activity2.java:25)

I have already confirmed that the index/ position variable is passing correctly. If anyone has any suggestions as to how to find the null pointer error, I would love the assistance.

Comment: Have you tried moving textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_b_text_view); from onActivityCreated to onCreateView?

Comment: An excellent guess! but sadly, I tried that already too. No such luck

Comment: And have you tried replacing textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_b_text_view); by textView = (TextView) getView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_b_text_view);

Comment: Ah Ha! Brilliant, so the answer was to both move it to the onCreateView AND to reference the view as opposed to the getActivity(); Many thanks K3. Would you like to answer below so I can select your as the correct answer?

Comment: sure, just did it :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Fragment B,

Try to replace `textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_b_text_view)` by  `textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_b_text_view)` and move it from onActivityCreated() to onCreateView().

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not getView() but just plain view. Whatever the view is in onCreateView (inflater.inflate....) needs to be used

Comment: K3v. would you mind updating your answer to change the getView(). to view. so that I can select yours as correct? Just don't want someone else to come by and try exactly what you have posted as it will cause a crash

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is when you can try to find the ID.

Try this `textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_b_texT_view)` where this `view` is your `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);`.

Comment: Definitely correct, though it needs to be moved to the onCreateView from the onActivityCreated for it to work